# Does Lynchwood have any story related quests?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm on my first playthrough of Borderlands 2.

I just got what appears to be the final questline of the game ("Where Angels Fear to Tread"), but I've never been forced to go into Lynchwood despite it being accessible much earlier in the game.

I picked up several quests from the Lynchwood bounty board earlier and noticed that they are the same level as Where Angels Fear to Tread.

I guess my real question is: Should I do the Lynchwood quests before "Where Angels Fear to Tread" ?

Comment: This may be more of an opinion related question. There are a lot of side missions that make for a fun play while in Lynchwood, however, if you are more for skipping side missions and going through the story mission then stick with the story. There is a very tough boss fight with a Skaag that can drop some nice loot in Lynchwood.

Comment: there`s  a few bosses in Lynchwood for farming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are no direct story missions that take you to Lynchwood.

Lynchwood actually differs to most other locations in that the enemies there scale to your level (most other locations have a fixed level). In normal mode, this is capped at level 30 (enemies spawn at level 32). This means it won't get any easier if your delay.

However, there is a wealth of backstory to be gotten by completing the Lynchwood missions.

And finally, you're actually still a way from the end of the game...

Answer (score 1):

The Lynchwood area does NOT count as a main story mission. However, if you plan on playing the follow-up game to Borderlands 2, Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel!, I would definitely recommend playing through this area, as the Sheriff of Lynchwood in Borderlands 2 actually ends up being a playable character in Pre-Sequel as Nisha, the Lawbringer. Also, it dives pretty deep into Brick's backstory and some of the things he's endured since the first game.